# Will inheritance break encapsulation?

Tags: java, inheritance, encapsulation

Let's say I have a CSV file and I create a class called `CsvFile` which extends from `java.io.File`. This class can parse a CSV file and return some data like how many columns are in the file. It can also be used for functions which takes `java.io.File` as input. Like F`ileUtils.copyFile(File from, File to)`.

My colleague thinks I expose too much from inheritance. His idea is to wrap `java.io.File` by holding it in a private property, instead of inheriting it. He think exposing all public method/property from file breaks encapsulation, but I take it as a benefit since we get all functions in `java.io.File` for free.

What do you think?

Comment: Either or I think not, but combining both is the way.  First inheritance so that the wheel is not reinvented, than to patterns that encapsulate so that the wheel serves its purpose.

Answer (score 15):

I would rather agree with your colleague: inheriting `java.util.File` would expose methods that are not applicable to `CsvFile` objects, such as `list()`, `listFiles()`, `setExecutable()`, and so on.

Making `java.util.File` a property behind a getter sounds like a better choice: it does not reveal irrelevant operations to the users of your class, and lets you inherit from a base class of your choice.

Comment: to add to the answer: yes, in this case inheritance will break encapsulation by leaking the implementation detail that a CVS file is implemented using a java.io.File

Comment: it might not be a case of either-or. Inherit to customize, than wrap to narrow to the methods you wish to expose.

Comment: Either or I think not, but combining both is the way. First inheritance so that the wheel is not reinvented, than to patterns that encapsulate so that the wheel serves its purpose.

Comment: But you lose the benefit of using java.io.file as base class. It will be weird to do FileUtils.copyFile(csvFile.getFile(), toFile). Second, you only listed some function that might no be used for a file, but that is the problem of java's implementation or the OS. I want to add there is some functions that can be used in inheritance like getMtime(), getSize(), rename()...

Comment: @Feng It's not *that* weird is it? And to your second point, you can still do all those things through `getFile()`, though it might be cleaner to implement those methods explicitly in `CsvFile` and let it delegate to the underlying `File` field (and not expose the `File` at all). It puts limitations on the use of `CsvFile`, but it makes its interface much simpler and thereby easier to use.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I thought about it last night. I would say our discussion may be affected by java.io.file. I am thinking it might not be the problem of the concept of inheritance, but the problem of java.io.File itself. This class is ambiguous and does contains some functions that should belongs to "Folder", or some specific file type like executable. It just contains too much specific functions that overwhelmed us. I would rather say java.io.File isn't a good class to extends.

Comment: @Feng I agree. I was surprised to learn that `java.io.File` is not marked `final`. In cases when your base class is better suited for inheritance than `java.io.File`, inheriting may be a proper choice, even though it leaks out the fact that your class is implemented using a particular base.

Comment: I don't even consider it's a leak. You will "leak" it anyway when you doing csvFile.getFile(), right?

Comment: @Feng It's "leaking" fundamentally different kinds of information: `getFile` tells your users that your class can provide them with a `File`, while inheriting from a `File` tells your users that your class *is* a `File`.

Answer (score 5):

I think it all depends of the purpose of the class.   If you are truly trying to extend the behavior then I would say it makes sense.  If you are not extending behavior of File but are just making a CSV object then encapsulation would limit its behaviors to only what it intention is.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider making it more generic so it can accept a CSV-formatted InputStream or Reader from a wide variety of sources that cannot (or cannot easily) emit to the filesystem. You can still have a java.io.File setter/constructor for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a great debate.  Your colleague is on the right side of history on this one.  In general the question of inheritance comes down to the relationships of is-a vs. has-a. In general it is more flexible to use composition than inheritance.  In your case its a close call.  After all a csv file isa file.  saying csvfile has-a file does not even sound right.  What might be considered as well is to do the inheritance but than wrap the inherited file so that only those CSV file methods that you want are exposed. I would also look into some design patterns around this where you want to inherit from A but expose a more limited interface to the world. I am almost sure there is a design pattern for this. just can't remember the name ....

"Either or I think not, but combining both is the way. First inheritance so that the wheel is not reinvented, than to patterns that encapsulate so that the wheel serves its purpose."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my point of view is too liberal but...
Encapsulation and inheritance are there for a reason. (Watch the 'evolution' from assemblers to high level languages.) That reason is the programmer. With higher level abstractions/paradigms you can write better code. The trick is to define 'better' of course. For me this is maintainability, self documentation and code reuse. That's why I would choose the encapsulation over inheritance in your particular case. Maybe it's a bit more work to write it once, but sooooo much easier to maintain in the future. (Assuming this CSV stuff is part of a bigger project of course.)

Answer (score 0):

The approach your colleague mentions also has the benefit that your API becomes very small by only exposing methods you really need - which makes it clear how to the user how to use your class (you can think of your public API as some sort of documentation).

Answer (score 0):

As to your question

> Will inheritance break encapsulation?

Then, according to Joshua Bloch's Effective Java, inheritance always breaks encapsulation:

> Unlike method invocation, inheritance violates encapsulation
>   [Snyder86]. In other words, a subclass depends on the implementation
>   details of its superclass for its proper function.

Regarding whether you should use inheritance or composition, as many people already said, it depends on if your `CsvFile` is-a file, in the sense of `java.util.File`.